# Which is more efficient creating a new table or using cache data?

Tags: database, oracle, caching, query-optimization

I have a table named 'user_phones' that has 40 columns. I have to run a process to validate my user and for this I have to check only 5 columns of 'user phones' and after validation I have to update the data through another process in that 5 columns.

So what should I do?

1) I create new tables having these 5 columns only.

2) OR should I transfer the users data (5 columns) into cache, so that while validating it should validate through cache and while updating it update both table and cache.

Which one is more efficient and optimal?

Comment: What sort of code are you propsing for these methods? It's not clear what you really mean, particularly by "transfer ... into cache"

Comment: Please describe the columns of your user_phones table: Looking at the number of columns, it sound like its not normalized.

Comment: Why do either of those two? Why not validate against the table (the one with the 40 columns). Then, the next process updates that table (the same one with its 40 columns). Nothing you've said indicates that this will cause a performance issue; and, it has the advantage of being simple.

Comment: Five Coloums: 
1)last_transaction_dateandtime
2)last_transactionid
3)MSISDN
4)USERID
5)last_transactionstatus.
So when the same user ask for another transaction that time we have to validate user through these columns as my product has a constraint that there should be a time difference between two transactions done by a user.
This table is used for so many processes, as i have to use only a small part of it.
Transfer to cache-i mean to say load the data into cache like we load system preferences at the start,so that we don't need to access user_phones for every transaction while validating.